# Dart: How to factorise function with the different return type

Tags: flutter, dart, refactoring

I have a few similar functions in my project that works the same but have different return types. Is it possible for me to factorise them into 1 function to reduce code reducndancy?

Below is my code sample:

```
class A {
    final String code;
    final String name;
}
```

```
class B {
    final String name;
    final String leaveDate;
}
```

```
List<A> testFunc(String value, List<A> list) {
  List<A> result = [];

  for (var E in list) {
    if (E.name!.toLowerCase().contains(value)) {
      result.add(E);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

```
List<B> testFun1(String value, List<B> list) {
  List<B> result = [];

  for (var E in list) {
    if (E.name!.toLowerCase().contains(value)) {
      result.add(E);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

I have tired to pass out `List<dynamic>` but it does seem working on my project.

Comment: You mean to use Generics?

Comment: @MendelG yes, or is there any other way that can help me to achieve what I need

Comment: In this case you would need `A` and `B` to have a common super type in order to call `.name` on either type. Then `testFun` can accept a generic `<T extends SuperTypeWhichDefinesNameGetter>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

- Make `A` and `B` both derive from a common base interface that provides a `name` getter:

  ```dart
  abstract interface class HasName {
    String get name;
  }

  class A implements HasName {
    final String code;

    @override
    final String name;

    A({required this.code, required this.name});
  }

  class B implements HasName {
    @override
    final String name;

    final String leaveDate;

    B({required this.name, required this.leaveDate});
  }

  List<T> testFunc<T extends HasName>(String value, List<T> list) {
    List<T> result = [];

    for (var e in list) {
      if (e.name.toLowerCase().contains(value)) {
        result.add(e);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  ```
- Alternatively make your generic function use callback for the getter:

  ```dart
  List<T> testFunc<T>(String value, List<T> list, String Function(T) getName) {
    List<T> result = [];

    for (var e in list) {
      if (getName(e).toLowerCase().contains(value)) {
        result.add(e);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  ```

  and then call it with something like `testFunc('foo', listOfA, (a) => a.name)`.

If you want to give up static type safety and to use duck-typing instead, you can treat `List` elements as `dynamic`:

```dart
List<T> testFunc<T>(String value, List<T> list) {
  List<T> result = [];

  for (var e in list) {
    if ((e as dynamic).name.toLowerCase().contains(value)) {
      result.add(e);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: will there be a big difference in terms of the performance between the 2nd way and the 3rd way (duck-typing)?

Comment: @Leong Using `dynamic` inherently incurs a runtime cost.   Whether that cost is big or not is something that you would need to determine based on your inputs.

Comment: can I know how can I test? I am quite new to flutter, so I'm not quite familiar with these...

Comment: @Leong You use a [`Stopwatch`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) object to measure how long operations take.  But unless you're doing this thousands of times or more, I doubt that you'll notice much performance difference from using `dynamic`.